# Long version of the statement

Tags: python, list

```
x = [d if d == z[i] and x[i] == "-" else x[i] for i in range(len(z))]
```

Can someone tell what this statement means by writing the long version?

Comment: Is this from a Hangman game? It looks like something someone might write to apply a letter guess in Hangman.

Comment: @user2357112 supports Monica yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code is equivalent to this:

```
y = []
for i in range(len(z)):
    if d == z[i] and x[i] == "-":
        y.append(d)
    else:
        y.append(x[i])
x = y
```

Comment: Nope. No x=[] because then it will fail with x[i].

Comment: Yeah, you'd need a temporary variable for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is the long version

```
y=[]
for i in range(len(z)):
    if d == z[i] and x[i] == '-':
       y.append(i)
    else:
       y.append(x[i])
```

Comment: And finally `x = y`.